# How do you use Vertex Weight Transfer from a Line Art modifier to transfer the weights to a group on the Greace Pencil object with a different name?

Tags: vertex-weights, lineart

It's possible (likely?) that I misunderstand how this functionality is supposed to work, but I believe that if I set the Target on a Vertex Weight Transfer and don't select "Match Output" it doesn't matter what I name the Target vertex group on the Grease Pencil Object. But I'm getting unexpected behavior with the following procedure, that seems to suggest to me that the Vertex Group names must always match, leaving me to wonder what the point of the "Target" field is:

This is on Blender 3.0

1. I start with a cube and add a grease pencil object with  a line art modifier targeted to the cube as an object.  Looks as I would expect. [image: Screen shot of a cube]
2. I add a vertex group to the cube, calling it "LINES.nolines" and I assign a value of 1.0 to the vertices of the top face (line art is temporarily hidden to make the screen shot clear).[image]
3. I open up the Vertex Weight Transfer section of the Line Art modifier, and I add a Filter Source of "LINES.nolines"  I do **not** select Match Output. [image]
4. I add a Vertex Group to the Line Art object called "LINES.nolines" and set the Target of the Vertex Weight Transfer to "LINES.nolines"[image]
5. I add an Opacity modifier onto the Grease Pencil stack, set the Opacity to zero and the Vertex Group under influence to "LINES.nolines"  Looks like I would expect.  [image]
6. Now I go back to the Object Data Properties tab for the and I rename the Vertex Group to "nolines".  My grease pencil lines disappear, presumably because the weight transfer on the Line Art modifier is still trying to find a group called "Lines.nolines" and now isn't activated since it's in an invalid state.  Nothing too strange yet. [image]
7. Going back to the Modifiers tab, both of the references to the now non-existent "LINES.nolines" group on the Grease Pencil object are red, as anticipated.  [image]
8. I change the Vertex Weight Transfer Target to "nolines" but the Grease Pencil lines do not reappear. [image]  *I expected all of the edges to have grease pencil lines at this point.*
9. I change the Influence Vertex Group of the Opacity Modifier to be nolines.  I expected to have the top face without visible edges as in step 5, however, now all edges are opaque, suggesting that the Vertex Weight transfer isn't happening.[image]

I assume that the reason that I can select a Target for the Vertex Weight Transfer means that I don't have to name the target vertex group the same as the source vertex group, otherwise I'd just use Match Output.  Do I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

[image]

Comment: The opacity modifier works even when I keep the Target blank. Also disabling or enabling Match Output seems to change nothing (Blender 3.4 Alpha). Thanks for the tutorial, this is the only info I found about this feature :)

Comment: No problem, @MumuMundo